# what method can I used to encrypt a string value in a windows mobile 8.1 project c#

Tags: c#, mobile, cryptography

what method can I used to encrypt a string value in a windows mobile 8.1 project.I have tried many cryptography methods but they are not supported in windows mobile.

I got following error when I tried to install cryptography packages from NuGet.

> Error     Could not install package xxxxx. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp, Version=v8.1',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Comment: google "windows phone 8.1 c# encrypt string" provides the following results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745103/encrypt-string-aes-windows-phone-8-1 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is available with `ProtectedData.Protect` function:

```
// Convert the string to a byte[].
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystringvalue);

// Encrypt the bytes by using the Protect() method.
byte[] encryptedBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(inputBytes, null);
```